# Use Pandas to list all values of a second column and count of the first column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

I can use groupby to show the size of the group of combinations:

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).size()

A  B
1  2    1
   3    1
4  6    1
```

How can I combine the unique values of B into a list and also display the size of A like this?

```
A  B
1  2,3  2
4  6    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['B'].astype(str).groupby(df['A']).agg([','.join,'size'])
Out[134]: 
  join  size
A           
1  2,3     2
4    6     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Group only on A and use `.agg` specifying a dictionary to use for each column.

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B': list, 'A': 'size'}).rename(columns={'A': 'Size'})

        B  Size
A              
1  [2, 3]     2
4     [6]     1
```